# Powershell Module where to store user settings

Tags: powershell, build, module, settings

I'm developing a PowerShell based build automation toolbox (http://www.crawler-lib.net/powershell-build-tools-samples). It is a powershell module This toolbox will be installed in the 32Bit and 64 Bit PowerShell module directory, because it can be executed via the NuGet Console in Visual Studio (which is a 32 Bit PowerShell host) and the PowerShell ISE (which is 64 Bit on 64 Bit OS).

I want to provide the developers and users of the toolbox an easy way to set their tools locations or override the automatic detection of the toolbox. So I have to store a properties or XML file with the settings for this. What is a good (standard) way to store such settings for a powershell module?

Comment: Hmm cmdlets with user profile preferences, don't know I've ever seen such a thing. Pre-defined defaults, yes, but no overridable persistent settings. If I wanted to load up your stuff with my powershell session, I'd put calls to it in my powershell profile files.

Comment: I would think using environment variables would be the way to go

Comment: I don't understand how this can be done with environment variables. The user want to configure the location of multiple tools like NuGet, Mercurial, etc. Maybe other settings like credentials and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most tools I see follow Unix convention and put user preference files in the user's home directory. For example, Mercurial puts its user config file there, named `mercurial.ini`. There are other locations that Windows wants these files, but I like the user's root: it is the easiest place to find and get to.

Now you just get to decide on format. `:-)` I like JSON, since it isn't as verbose as XML, but I think XML might be easier in your users. There is much better tooling for XML and it's been around longer.

Comment: I will look at several locations (including the user directory) for the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer to use:

```
$AppName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($PSCommandPath);
$myCompanyName = "myCompanyName";
```

* use [System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::LocalApplicationData if you do not want to put it in a roaming profile

```
$ApplicationDataFolder = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::ApplicationData);
```

* build the path

```
$myStorageFolder = ($ApplicationDataFolder | Join-Path -ChildPath $myCompanyName) | Join-Path -ChildPath $AppName;
```